# How do I play RuneScape with minimal lagging?

Tags: firefox, java, runescape

RuneScape is a Java-based MMORPG that on Ubuntu can only be accessed (or at least to my knowledge) via going to http://www.runescape.com/game.ws in a Java-supporting web browser (such as Firefox or Opera) with the required plugins. The problem is that in my experience RuneScape is very laggy when opened up in Firefox on 32 bit Ubuntu 15.04 (with 3.8 GB RAM with an Intel processor). I was just wondering if there was a way to improve the performance of RuneScape, on this platform (like accessing it in a different browser, for instance). I have previously tried using Wine to install the game client (which is designed for Microsoft Windows OSs) but it does not appear to work for me anymore, even though on previous versions of Ubuntu (I think it was 12.04) perhaps with previous game clients this method worked.

Comment: Their file download links are broken.

Comment: Namely https://copy.com/s/y88FzDr8iSgS/Public/RSU/opengl-browser-fix/java-wrapper.zip and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11631899/opensource/Perl/java-wrapper/java-wrapper.tar.gz (found on the description of the YouTube tutorial) are both broken.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~hikariknight/+archive/ubuntu/unix-runescape-client PPA has *unix-runescape-client* packages for all supported versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: How do I add the PPA using `sudo add-apt-repository`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play RuneScape locally without Wine using the [RuneScape Unix Client (RSU Client)](https://launchpad.net/~hikariknight/+archive/ubuntu/unix-runescape-client). Installation instructions for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hikariknight/unix-runescape-client   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install unix-runescape-client
```

You can use different java versions by editing the "preferredjava" setting inside `~/.config/runescape/share/settings.conf`
along with several other settings.

*Your frame rate in game very much comes down to the hardware installed on your system. You can have limitations due to this. Some of the most important components on your computer for higher fps are your graphics card, total RAM and your CPU. The older or less powerful they are, the more likely you are to suffer from a poor frame rate.*<sup>**1**</sup> You can free up maybe half a gigabyte of RAM by installing a lightweight desktop environment that you can optionally select to login to instead of Unity.

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>[View and improve your frame rate in RuneScape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsHmuGJg50g) by Mod_Rambo at Jagex</sub>

Comment: Well I suppose I managed to install the client correctly, following your instructions. But I can't notice any real improvements, speed-wise. It's still lagging significantly.